# How to manipulate column data in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to manipulate column data in postgres

When I run the query-

```
SELECT t.date::varchar 
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2020-02-27'
                     , timestamp '2020-03-01'
                     , interval  '1 day') AS t(date);
```

it returns -

```
2020-02-27 00:00:00
2020-02-28 00:00:00
2020-02-29 00:00:00
2020-03-01 00:00:00
```

I want -

```
20200227
20200228
20200229
20200301
```

Removed '-' and truncated from end.
Can someone guide

Comment: [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you don't specifically need some features of a [`varchar`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html), by default use `text` instead.
2. You don't need to cast every time - [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) will do that automatically once it detects your step is an `interval`. That's unless you specifically want the `generate_series(timestamp,timestamp,inteval)` variant, not `generate_series(timestamptz,timestamptz,inteval)`.
3. If you cast to be explicit, cast your dates as [`date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). Regardless of whether you leave it as text literal or make them actual dates, PostgreSQL will have to cast them to match the function definition.
4. If you're planning to group things by a text-based date or do that to truncate timestamps, consider [`date_bin()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) and [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) as well as simply holding things as a native `date` type. It'll take less space, run faster and enable native date-specific functions.
5. Make sure you're using [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) to its full potential - it can save a lot of formatting later.

```sql
SELECT to_char(t.date,'YYYYMMDD') as date
FROM   generate_series('2020-02-27'
                     , '2020-03-01'
                     , interval  '1 day') AS t(date);
--   date
------------
-- 20200227
-- 20200228
-- 20200229
-- 20200301
```